# Mono TextTransform.exe

Tags: c#, .net, mono, t4, css

I'm trying to use the TextTransform executable from MonoDevelop.  I'm using sharpdevelop as my IDE and created a simple texttemplate file to check it out and all went well.  The file was generated on save.  When I went to use the executable I was continually running into errors about not finding files.  As an example I was using `<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>` and this would output when I tried using the executable:

> "ERROR Metadata file 'System.Core' could not be found".

I tried a couple different things like passing `-P` argument(though I'm not sure I did that right).  It wasn't until I changed the tt file itself to use `<#@ assembly name="System.Core.dll" #>` instead of "System.Core" that the executable was successful.  However, after changing to include the file extension SharpDevelop now gives this output when I save the tt file.

> Error loading code-completion information for System.Core.dll from System.Core.dll:
>   Could not find assembly file.

Is there something I'm missing in order to get both to work?  I don't really need both but would like to understand why this happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems like a bug in TextTransform.exe since I would expect it to allow an assembly name instead of the filename. I can also reproduce it in MonoDevelop with the following T4 template.

```
<#@ template language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>

<html><body>
 The date and time now is: <#= DateTime.Now #>
</body></html>
```

The above template works fine with SharpDevelop 4.4.

Changing the template so it uses System.Core.dll in the assembly directive also works with SharpDevelop. The code completion error can be ignored. This error is being incorrectly generated by the parser. So you could just leave the assembly directive using System.Core.dll for now.

Visual Studio also supports both versions of the template with or without the .dll file extension.

Interestingly SharpDevelop actually uses Mono's T4 templating engine to run these T4 templates. They are obviously doing something different.